# Как запретить клик на кнопку, на 20 минут после её нажатия java?

Tags: java, android

Как запретить клик на кнопку, на 20 минут после её нажатия с таймером обратного отсчета?

Полный код:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
 
import java.util.Locale;
 
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 
    TextView timeCount;
    Button start, reset;
 
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
 
    boolean timerRunning;
 
    long startTimer=600000; //1000 milliseconds in 1 second, here i am taking 10 minutes
    long remainingTime;
    
    private static final int expTime = 20 * 60 * 1000;
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
    "app_data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 
        start.setEnabled(prefs.getLong("expires_in", 0) <= 
        System.currentTimeMillis());
 
        timeCount = findViewById(R.id.text_count);
        start = findViewById(R.id.start);
        reset = findViewById(R.id.reset);
        remainingTime = startTimer;
 
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            
           start.setEnabled(false);
           prefs.putLong("expires_in", System.currentTimeMillis()+expTime); 
            
                if(timerRunning){
                    pauseTimer();
                }
                else{
                    startTimer();
                }
            }
        });
 
        reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                resetTimer();
            }
        });
    }
 
    public void  startTimer(){
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(remainingTime, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                remainingTime = millisUntilFinished;
                updateCountTime();
            }
 
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                timerRunning = false;
                updateButton();
            }
        }.start();
 
        timerRunning = true;
        updateButton();
    }
 
    public void pauseTimer(){
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        timerRunning = false;
        updateButton();
    }
 
    public void resetTimer(){
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        timerRunning = false;
        remainingTime = startTimer;
        updateCountTime();
        updateButton();
    }
 
    public void updateCountTime(){
        int minutes = (int) (remainingTime / 1000) / 60;
        int seconds = (int) (remainingTime / 1000) % 60;
 
        String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
        timeCount.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
    }
 
    public void updateButton(){
        if(timerRunning){
            reset.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            start.setText("Pause");
        }else{
            start.setText("Start");
 
            if(remainingTime<1000){
                start.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else{
                start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
 
            if(remainingTime<startTimer){
                reset.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else{
                reset.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ошибку выдаёт в коде:

```
prefs.putLong("expires_in", System.currentTimeMillis()+expTime);
```

Подсвечивает красным

```
putlong java Cannot resolve method 'putLong' in 'SharedPreferences'
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Еще один вариант - установить время протухания кнопки через 20 минут и сохранить его в память приложения. И дальше проверку просто сделать и все:

```
private static final int expTime = 20 * 60 * 1000;
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
  "app_data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

post_data.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
                    ....
           post_data.setEnabled(false);
           prefs.edit().putLong("exp_time",System.currentTimeMillis()+expTime).apply();  
      }
});
```

и дальше при запуске приложения вы можете проверять сохраненное значение:

```
post_data.setEnabled(prefs.getLong("expires_in", 0) <= System.currentTimeMillis());
```

таким образом если время протухания <= текущего времени то кнопка работает, если нет то можно вывести уведомление.

Comment: В моём варианте выдаёт ошибку `putlong java Cannot resolve method 'putLong' in 'SharedPreferences'`

Comment: не могли бы вы показать ваш фрагмент кода который на текущий момент выдает ошибку?

Comment: Выше скинул полный код. Ошибку выдаёт в коде:

`prefs.putLong("expires_in", System.currentTimeMillis()+expTime);`

Comment: а просто если `System.currentTimeMillis()` записать оно запишется? без времени истечения? У вас красным что-то подсвечивается?

Comment: putLong с ошибкой которую я указал

Comment: `SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
    "app_data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` это в oncreate переместите

Comment: тогда в `prefs.putLong("expires_in", System.currentTimeMillis()+expTime);` `prefs.` подчеркивает красной линией с ошибкой `Variable 'prefs' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final`

Comment: Если я делаю `final SharedPreferences prefs` то тогда снова `putLong` выдаёт ту же ошибку

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115150/discussion-between-andrew-and-buratino-apps).

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте кнопку заблокированной по умолчанию. Выставьте таймер, чтобы он с периодичностью раз в секунду проверял, прошло ли 20 минут с последнего нажатия, и если прошло, тогда кнопка становится активной. При нажатии текущие дату и время + 20 минут нужно сохранить в локальное хранилище, с которым и будет сверяться приложение при срабатывании таймера.

Comment: а можно просто создать уведомление аларм-менеджеру через 20 минут оповестить приложение, или если нет желания мучаться с алармами и таймерами, просто вставить в начале кода кнопки проверку и показать юзеру тост с сообщением, что осталось столько-то минут, а время нажатия хранить в шеред преференсах.

Comment: Может кто то скинет пример с Ютуба. А то с таймером не как не получается.